# Is there any way to choose google drive files from HTML page to upload them to my server?

Tags: google-drive-api

I want to browse files of Google drive from my web page and then select those files to upload them to my server, just like we browse files of system's hard drive to upload through HTML form. Is this even possible?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You want to upload files in own Google Drive to own server using own browser. If my understanding is correct, I think that this can be achieved. As a sample flow, how about this? 1. Retrieve file list using the files.list method of Drive API. 2. Download the files using the files.get and files.export methods of Drive API. 3. Upload the files. In this case, it uses the fetch method of Javascript. The documents of Drive API are [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files) and [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/js).

Comment: look at the Google picker (https://developers.google.com/picker/docs/). Bear in mind that it's closed source!